# Is that real show count view pages with use Jekyll?

Tags: html, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Interesting question for me. can I set a counter on each page and then on the Blog page to see how many times I've looked through the pages?

Comment: Google Analytics or some other analytics tracker could show you how many page views you have. Displaying it on your website would take some Javascript acrobatics though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Jekyll typically does not allow you to do such a thing. Jekyll has no database in which it can keep score of the amount of hits, and the Ruby code is only executed during build. You need to load a third party application (micro service) through javascript to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tool delevpoled by busuanzi, just include two lines in html:

```html
<script async src="//busuanzi.ibruce.info/busuanzi/2.3/busuanzi.pure.mini.js"></script>
<span id="busuanzi_container_site_pv">Total visits to this site: <span id="busuanzi_value_site_pv"></span></span>
```

author's website: [不蒜子 - 极简网页计数器](https://busuanzi.ibruce.info/)